# AngularJS ui.router root state should be called always during app init

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on web application using AngularJS and have used ui.router for routing.

I have configured the app

```
.state('init', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'LocalizationCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'partials/common/init.html'
  })
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'partials/auth/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    resolve: {
      skipIfLoggedIn: skipIfLoggedIn
    }
  });
```

In init I load the localization json from server

If I hit the following URL it all works fine
http://localhost/app/index.html

However if I hit the following URL or any other state directly the localization files do not load
http://localhost/app/index.html#/login

How can I make sure that when app is loaded first using any URL the localization code should execute and not bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

```
/ Bu default go to state - 
angular.module('yourModuleName').run(["$location", function ($location) {
        $location.url('/');
}]);
```

So, when you refresh or take your web application, your site will go to url `/`, so it should invoke your state, `init` to work.

**Or you can use `$state` to go to a state upon starts**

```
/ Bu default go to state - 
angular.module('yourModuleName').run(["$state", function ($state) {
        $state.go('init');
}]);
```

Comment: Have you checked this code ? Isn't this code will redirect every page refresh to "/" ? I dont think its a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple there is a property "**Resolve**" you can use that.
In your parent state you can write this -

```
.state('parentState', {
        resolve : {
             localize : function() {
                      //Localization code here
             }

       }
};
```

Resolve will ensure that your localization work will be done before controller is loaded.

Comment: In this case I will have to add localize in all states and there are almost 50 states. Is there any simpler way like adding something in app.run or so.

Comment: why all states as i said add this to your parent state only it will work.
you should have a correct heirarchy of states.
like - app, app.user, app.user.details, app.login, here app is parent state.

Comment: There are multiple parent states. I have not grouped all states under 1.

Comment: This is the drawback of your application make a parent and attach all states with that then only you can have a solution.
Making many parents is not a good approach to make an app.